# Clustering with shared session - object not serialized error

Tags: java

I have an environment where 2 load-balanced clustered tomcats pointing to same application.

When they run under sticky session and not shared session, they works fine. Now I am implementing failover for tomcat. ie If one one fails other handles the sessions that handled by the failed one. And I am trying in-memory session replication.

When I enable this feature, I am getting some exceptions like

> org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager
>   requestCompleted SEVERE: Unable to
>   serialize delta request for sessionid
>   [68930629D2318EFAC06F3D75FFA162D0.tomcat2]
>   java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.json.JSONObject
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1156)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1474)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1392)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1150)
>           at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:326)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaRequest$AttributeInfo.writeExternal(DeltaRequest.java:374)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaRequest.writeExternal(DeltaRequest.java:272)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaRequest.serialize(DeltaRequest.java:287)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.serializeDeltaRequest(DeltaManager.java:640)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager.requestCompleted(DeltaManager.java:1120)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.send(ReplicationValve.java:550)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.sendMessage(ReplicationValve.java:537)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.sendSessionReplicationMessage(ReplicationValve.java:519)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.sendReplicationMessage(ReplicationValve.java:430)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:363)
>           at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:210)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>           at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
>           at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Sep 11, 2009 7:21:06 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager
>   requestCompleted SEVERE: Unable to
>   serialize delta request for sessionid
>   [68930629D2318EFAC06F3D75FFA162D0.tomcat2]
>   java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.json.JSONObject

Since JSON is not serialized I am putting it inside an ArrayList before setting it in session. And it works fine in non shared session environment.

What I need to do for enabling fail over? (Please done tell something like don't save the object in session. Its not only the one object which causing error. I am getting errors for other objects like  Data source etc.. as well)

Thanks in advance

Umesh

Edit: Have already implemented serialization and transient

public class ABC implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID=2007L;
    public static transient DataSource source;

Getting this error
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
...
storing attribute 'ABC' with value NOT_SERIALIZED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put it inside an object with the field storing the reference marked as transient.

Comment: No. Though ArrayList does mark its internal Object[] array as transient it calls ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(array[i]) for each item in array. Why no create a simple holder class (struct) for the JSONObject?

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the objects AND need them, then implement serializable & the necessary readObject(), writeObject() methods.

Any objects that fail either need to be extended to implement serializable, or not stored in the session directly, but placed in another object as a transient field. You need to make your application robust enough to rebuild these objects after the failover happens.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when writing anything to session it must implement java.io.Serializable interface